# Inventory Stock item

Tags: magento2.4, custom, custom-field, msi, multi-source-inventory

I am trying to add a custom field to the MSI source item. Please check the following screenshot-

[image]

I have overwrite product_form.xml in app/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml as follows -

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="sources" sortOrder="5" component="Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi/js/product/form/source-items">
        
        <dynamicRows name="assigned_sources" component="Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows-grid" template="ui/dynamic-rows/templates/grid" sortOrder="20">
            
            <container name="record" component="Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record">           
                
                <field name="custom1" formElement="input" sortOrder="51">
                    <settings>
                        <dataType>text</dataType>
                        <dataScope>custom1</dataScope>
                        <label translate="true">Custom Stock Status 1</label>                        
                        <disabled>false</disabled>
                                                
                    </settings>
                </field>
                           
            </container>
            
        </dynamicRows>
        
    </fieldset>
    
</form>
```

And added field as **custom1** in databases table **inventory_source_item** using following code in /etc/db_scema.xml

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    
    
    <table name="inventory_source_item" resource="default" engine="innodb">
        
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="custom1" nullable="false" length="255"/>
        
    </table>
    
</schema>
```

But custom field data not saving in databases. Please help me about this.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Mohamed Abbas,
I have added di.xml with the following content  -

```
    <preference for="Magento\Inventory\Model\ResourceModel\SourceItem\SaveMultiple" type="Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\SourceItem\SaveMultiple" /> `
```

`<preference for="Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceItemInterface" type="Custom\Module\Api\Data\SourceItemInterface" />`

And - Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\SourceItem\SaveMultiple  as follows -

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\SourceItem;

use Magento\Inventory\Model\ResourceModel\SourceItem ;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Inventory\Model\ResourceModel\SourceItem as SourceItemResourceModel;
use Custom\Module\Api\Data\SourceItemInterface;


/**
 * Implementation of SourceItem save multiple operation for specific db layer
 *
 * Save Multiple used here for performance efficient purposes over single save operation
 */
class SaveMultiple  extends \Magento\Inventory\Model\ResourceModel\SourceItem\SaveMultiple
{
    /**
     * @var ResourceConnection
     */
    private $resourceConnection;

    /**
     * @param ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
     */
    public function __construct(
        ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
    ) {
        $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
    }

    /**
     * Multiple save source items
     *
     * @param SourceItemInterface[] $sourceItems
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(array $sourceItems)
    {
        if (!count($sourceItems)) {
            return;
        }
        $connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
        $tableName = $this->resourceConnection->getTableName(SourceItemResourceModel::TABLE_NAME_SOURCE_ITEM);

        $columnsSql = $this->buildColumnsSqlPart([
            SourceItemInterface::SOURCE_CODE,
            SourceItemInterface::SKU,
            SourceItemInterface::QUANTITY,
            SourceItemInterface::STATUS,
            SourceItemInterface::CUSTOM1
        ]);
        $valuesSql = $this->buildValuesSqlPart($sourceItems);
        $onDuplicateSql = $this->buildOnDuplicateSqlPart([
            SourceItemInterface::QUANTITY,
            SourceItemInterface::STATUS,
            SourceItemInterface::CUSTOM1
        ]);
        $bind = $this->getSqlBindData($sourceItems);

        $insertSql = sprintf(
            'INSERT INTO `%s` (%s) VALUES %s %s',
            $tableName,
            $columnsSql,
            $valuesSql,
            $onDuplicateSql
        );
        $connection->query($insertSql, $bind);
    }

    /**
     * Build column sql part
     *
     * @param array $columns
     * @return string
     */
    private function buildColumnsSqlPart(array $columns): string
    {
        $connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
        $processedColumns = array_map([$connection, 'quoteIdentifier'], $columns);
        $sql = implode(', ', $processedColumns);
        return $sql;
    }

    /**
     * Build sql query for values
     *
     * @param SourceItemInterface[] $sourceItems
     * @return string
     */
    private function buildValuesSqlPart(array $sourceItems): string
    {
        $sql = rtrim(str_repeat('(?, ?, ?, ?), ', count($sourceItems)), ', ');
        return $sql;
    }

    /**
     * Get Sql bind data
     *
     * @param SourceItemInterface[] $sourceItems
     * @return array
     */
    private function getSqlBindData(array $sourceItems): array
    {
        $bind = [];
        foreach ($sourceItems as $sourceItem) {
            $bind[] = $sourceItem->getSourceCode();
            $bind[] = $sourceItem->getSku();
            $bind[] = $sourceItem->getQuantity();
            $bind[] = $sourceItem->getStatus();
            $bind[] = $sourceItem->getExtensionAttributes()->getCustom1();
        }
        return $bind;
    }

    /**
     * Build sql query for on duplicate event
     *
     * @param array $fields
     * @return string
     */
    private function buildOnDuplicateSqlPart(array $fields): string
    {
        $connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
        $processedFields = [];
        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            $processedFields[] = sprintf('%1$s = VALUES(%1$s)', $connection->quoteIdentifier($field));
        }
        $sql = 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ' . implode(', ', $processedFields);
        return $sql;
    }
}
```

and Custom\Module\Api\Data\SourceItemInterface

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Custom\Module\Api\Data;

use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data;
use Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataInterface;

/**
 * Represents amount of product on physical storage
 * Entity id getter is missed because entity identifies by compound identifier (sku and source_code)
 *
 * Used fully qualified namespaces in annotations for proper work of WebApi request parser
 *
 * @api
 */
interface SourceItemInterface extends \Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceItemInterface
{
    /**#@+
     * Constants for keys of data array. Identical to the name of the getter in snake case
     */
    const CUSTOM1 = 'custom1';
    
    

    
}
```

After Save from admin its shows error - **The stock item was unable to be saved. Please try again.**

Answer (score 0):

You have created only form for this, I Guess you have to create extension attribute for save the source item and get the same saved value for custom attribute.

Please follow the flow,

1. create entension attribute for
   `Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceItemInterface`
2. save the custom value into inventory source item table extend the
   below class
   vendor\magento\module-inventory\Model\ResourceModel\SourceItem\SaveMultiple.php
3. for render the saved values from database to form ,extend the below
   class
   vendor\magento\module-inventory\Model\SourceItemRepository.php